# Where is the Visual Studio 2015 Build Tools installed to?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, chocolatey

I installed the Microsoft Build Tools 2015 Update 3 using Chocolatey:
https://chocolatey.org/packages/microsoft-build-tools/14.0.25420.1

But I can't find where it actually installed the files.  Can't see anything in Program files etc.

Where are Microsoft Build Tools 2015 Update 3 installed to?

Comment: I don't know the exact path, but the best thing to do is search your drive(s) for msbuild.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Where It's At...

(♪ *I got two turntables, and a microphone* ♪)

You should be able to open the "Developer 2015 Command Prompt" (which should be in your start menu) and issue the `where msbuild` command to have the path echoed.

Typically (as of this writing), the build tools will be installed in

`%ProgramFiles%\Visual Studio\2015\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

(or `%ProgramFiles(x86)%...` if using the 32-bit version).

---

### For a bit more detail

Including some of the older install paths, see:
[Where is MSBuild.exe installed in Windows when installed using BuildTools_Full.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567280/where-is-msbuild-exe-installed-in-windows-when-installed-using-buildtools-full-e)

### Also, for future reference:

[Chocolatey FAQs](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/ChocolateyFAQs)

[Why doesn't a package install software to Program Files?](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/ChocolateyFAQs#why-doesnt-a-package-install-software-to-program-files)

**Note: in this instance, since it uses an msi file, it *does* install to Program Files.**